# Can Marshmallow auto-convert dot-delimited fields to nested JSON/dict in combination with unknown=EXCLUDE?

Tags: python-3.x, marshmallow

In trying to `load()` data with field names which are dot-delimited, using `unknown=INCLUDE` auto-converts this to nested dicts (which is what I want), however I'd like to do this with `unknown=EXCLUDE` as my data has a lot of properties I don't want to deal with.

It appears that with `unknown=EXCLUDE`, this auto-conversion does not happen and the dot-delimited field itself is passed to the schema, which of course is not recognized.  This is confirmed by not using the `unknown=` param at all, which raises a ValidationError.

Is it possible to combine `unknown=EXCLUDE` and still get nested data?  Or is there a better way to deal with this situation?

Thanks in advance!

```
# using marshmallow v3.7.1

from marshmallow import Schema, fields, INCLUDE, EXCLUDE

data = {'LEVEL1.LEVEL2.LEVEL3': 'FooBar'}

class Level3Schema(Schema):
    LEVEL3 = fields.String()

class Level2Schema(Schema):
    LEVEL2 = fields.Nested(Level3Schema)

class Level1Schema(Schema):
    LEVEL1 = fields.Nested(Level2Schema)

schema = Level1Schema()

print(schema.load(data, unknown=INCLUDE))
# prints: {'LEVEL1': {'LEVEL2': {'LEVEL3': 'FooBar'}}}

print(schema.load(data, unknown=EXCLUDE))
# prints: {}

print(schema.load(data))
# raises: marshmallow.exceptions.ValidationError: {'LEVEL1.LEVEL2.LEVEL3': ['Unknown field.']}
```